# Looking for the name of a specific numerical logic puzzle. Involves swapping digits for shapes

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-identification

I took an online assessment for a job and there was this really interesting section where you had to solve simple algebra problems, except the digits (not the numbers) were replaced by symbols.

An easy example would be something like this.

▲■ + ◊☺ = ◊☺■

What is the value of ▲?

I cannot find what the name of these puzzles are or where I can find more. Anyone recognize them?
They seem similar to rebus puzzles but I can't find any of this nature.

Update:

They are very similar to cryptarithmns as answered by @Jujustum. However, they don't seem to be fully correct, as the puzzles in the assessment sometimes are insolvable, and not all of the digits can be deduced.

For those wondering, the value of ▲ is

> 9.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I found 9■+10=10■, but I’m wondering if there are other solutions.

Comment: You are correct. The equations are incomplete, but there are digits you can be certain of. It's about deductive reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you’re looking for are **cryptarithms**. Here’s the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic).
The examples given in the page are mostly using letters for symbols.

Comment: This is almost it. Except the wiki seems to require you solving each digit. Whereas in the assessment examples not every digit is solvable. You have to reason out which ones are.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some of these puzzles here:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphametic